# Any way to host PHP locally inside a .net executable file

Tags: c#, php, .net, database, executable

I'd like to basically turn a php website with database into a .net executable file. I'd like everything to be internal. Is this possible or will I have to rewrite the entire project into C#?

Comment: It **MAY** be possible. PHP can be compiled into an executable under some, but **NOT ALL** circumstances. You'd be better off rewriting.

Comment: It is possible but not recommended, rewritting to C# would be your best/easiest option.

Comment: Curious to see how the webpages would be transformed into winforms

Comment: Your "solution" is "put everything in an .exe".  What's the actual "goal"???  I'd strongly urge you to revisit your requirements and re-think other possible solutions.  I honestly think you'll find much more reasonable "solutions".  IMHO...

Comment: @Snuffleupagus: why winforms? use MVC4....

Comment: @CarstenSchütte `into a .net executable file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to (should) rewrite the project in C#.

Of course, it is technically possible to integrate everything you need into one executable .NET file, but this solution will make use of lots of unsupported stuff, temp files or PInvoke calls, which you do not want to have in a managed environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was told that the computers using the app were ancient and it needs some vb5 type of application to assure that it ran on all systems.